# Shortcut to switch between 2 VSCode windows when there are several VSCode windows opened

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using a Mac.

I have several VSCode windows opened.

I would like to switch between only 2 (last viewed) windows. Does anyone know what is the keyboard shortcut to do so?

I tried command + `, but it went through all the opened VSCode windows one by one. Similarly for option + tab.

I tried control + w, it went through all the opened VSCode window too unless you use up and down keys to select.

Could anyone help?

Comment: This sounds like the detail about the specific application (VS Code) could be abstracted away from the question to generalize it, and then ask the question on a different, more appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Comment: To clarify, is it that you want it so that when you take a single action multiple times, the desktop environment cycles between only those two options for final selection (as opposed to cycling through all your VS Code windows for final selection)?

Comment: Ex. This sounds very similar to [this apple.se.com question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/479746). Maybe you should be asking this there instead.

Comment: Would an acceptable workaround be to move specifically those two VS Code windows to their own desktop space, separate from the rest of the VS Code windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following mapped to alt+tab, in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenRecent",
  "when": "!inRecentFilesPicker"
},
{
  "key": "alt+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInRecentFilesPicker",
  "when": "inQuickOpen && inRecentFilesPicker"
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePreviousInRecentFilesPicker",
  "when": "inQuickOpen && inRecentFilesPicker"
}
```

Comment: Is this about OS/desktop-level windows? Or is it about editor groups / files **within** a specific OS/desktop-level window?

Comment: Desktop-level. But I have to admit I am looking at the backup version from a Mac I… decommissioned.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>: switch to the previous window
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>: switch to the next window

These shortcuts allow you to switch between the last two Visual Studio Code windows.

OR

open command pallete <kbd>CMD+SHIFT+P</kbd> and search for `Window: Focus Next Group` or `Window: Focus Previous Group` commands to switch between the last two Visual Studio Code windows.

### Solution 2

- <kbd>Ctrl +1</kbd> Focus into Left Editor Group
- <kbd>Ctrl +2</kbd> Focus into Side Editor Group
- <kbd>Ctrl +3</kbd> Focus into Right Editor Group
- <kbd>Ctrl +K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+Left</kbd> Focus into Editor Group on the Left
- <kbd>Ctrl +K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd> Focus into Editor Group on the Right
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp/PageDow</kbd> to switch between panes.
- <kbd>⌘K ⌘←</kbd> / <kbd>⌘K ⌘→</kbd> Focus into previous/next editor group

### Solution 3

You have to edit `keybindings.json`. Use the Command Palette with <kbd>CMD+SHIFT+P</kbd>, `enter` "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)", and hit `enter`.

Then add to the end of the file:

```json
[
    // ...
    {
        "key": "ctrl+tab",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+tab", // or change custom shortcuts
        "command": "workbench.action.focusNextGroup"
    }
]
```

OR

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "f6", 
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateEditorGroups" 
    }
]
```

OR

```json
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor",
    "when": "!inEditorsPicker"
  }
]
```

Comment: You answered the wrong question, very thoroughly. They are having trouble navigating between VSCode windows, not editor groups.