# Shortcut to switch between 2 VSCode windows when there are several VSCode windows opened (repost)

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

(* I repost [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74744655/shortcut-to-switch-between-2-vscode-windows-when-there-are-several-vscode-window) I asked previously, because I found the accepted solution was not perfect. *)

I'm using a Mac.

I have several VSCode windows opened.

I would like to switch between only 2 (last viewed) windows. Does anyone know what is the keyboard shortcut to do so?

I tried <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, but it went through all the opened VSCode windows one by one. Similarly for option + tab.

I tried <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, it went through all the opened VSCode window too unless you use up and down keys to select.

I also adopted [the solution]((https://stackoverflow.com/a/74924591/702977) by adding `{"key": "alt+tab", "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenRecent", "when": "!inRecentFilesPicker"},`. However the problem is, after switching window, we lost the focus, we need to click on the editor again before editing.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to the same question, and I found your first "post" and came here from it. You don't need to ask the same question twice. Having two copies of it just makes finding the solution more difficult. If anyone knows how to switch between different windows of VSCode on a Mac, please leave an answer on the original question, so we can find it in one place.

Comment: @eksortso this is a slightly different question, just poorly asked. it's really about focusing editor groups, but the title is confusing. you can edit ti to clarify.

Comment: The two questions are identical, except for the top line and the "I also adopted" paragraph. Since I don't have a Mac and don't know the default VSCode key bindings for that system, I'm reluctant to edit the question myself. Instead, I recommend removing this copy, then returning to and editing the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Use whichever solution from that previous question you posted that you prefer, and then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><number></kbd> to focus the editor pane you want, where `<number>` is the 1-indexed number of the editor pane you want to focus. (it's 1-indexed because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> is for focusing the sidebar).

Comment: The question is about how to switch between the windows, not between the individual editors, and also not between the editor groups within the same window.

Comment: @eksortso read carefully. the question post links to another question post, which I refer to, and says that their problem for this question is that after switching windows, the editor group is no longer focused.

Comment: I did read carefully. They never explicitly mentioned _editor groups_ in this question, or in the original question that they linked twice to.

Comment: @eksortso "_However the problem is, after switching window, we lost the focus, we need to click on the editor again before editing._"